# Need C# sample for sending sms with Nokia PC Suite?

Tags: c#, sms, nokia

Nokia N70;
PC Suite 7.1.40.1

I'm able to send sms with pc suite and connected phone via bluetooth. But i want to be able to automate this and write some wraper (my own app) which will trigger send sms command in PC Suite... maybe somebody has some simple sample for start?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need the [Nokia PC Connectivity API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html) (note: Forum Nokia registration required for download). According to the blurb

*Developers can use the Content Access API to build PC applications that create, modify, and delete SMS and MMS messages. The API can be used to send and receive SMS and MMS messages.*